# Trying to post nested array to php with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I'm working on my first php/SQL database project and my goal is to store an array of checkbox values into a database.

On clicking the submit on the checkbox form, i am trying to post the array of checkbox values from my jquery doc to index.php

The success response is my index.php page, which i think is correct, so it all seems correct for me and i'm having a hard time figuring why

My array is generated from a series of .push() calls that update to determine when a box is checked it not and only submitted when i click my form submit, which should trigger the ajax post.

```
var checkArr = 
   [
      {id: "CB1", val: "checked"},
      {id: "CB3", val: ""},
      {id: "CB5", val: ""},
      {id: "CB4", val: "checked"},
      {id: "CB2", val: ""}
   ];


//SUBMIT CHECKBOX VALUES TO PHP
$('#submitCheck').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {checkArr:checkArr},
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                alert("ok");
                console.log(response);
            }
        });     
});
```

Here however when i check to see if the post worked i only return 'is not set'.

```
if(isset($_POST['checkArr'])){
    $arr = $_POST['checkArr'];
    echo $arr;
} else {
    echo 'Is not set';
}
```

I know there are many similar questions but i haven't found a solution in any of them unfortunately.
I found one thread that mentioned it might be redirecting me before the post can be processed so i removed the action from my form and nothing changed. I tried to stringify my output as json and still the same problem (even if stringify is redundant because of jquery).

Edit: Full code snippet

```
var checkArr = [];

//COLOUR ITEMS ON PAGE LOAD
$(document).ready(function(){
    var box = $(':checkbox');

    if(box.is(':checked')){
        box.parents("li").removeClass('incomplete');
        box.parents("li").addClass('complete');
    } else {
        box.parents("li").removeClass('complete');
        box.parents("li").addClass('incomplete');
    }   
});


//DELETE ITEM
$(document).on('click','.delete', function(){
    console.log('DELETED');
    var id = $(this).attr('id')//get target ID
    var item = $(this).closest('li');//targets the li element
    //AJAX
        $.ajax({
            url: 'delete.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 'id':id },
            success: function(response){
                if(response == 'ok') {
                    item.slideUp(500,function(){
                        item.remove();
                    });
                } else if(response == 'error') {
                    console.log("error couldn't delete");
                } else {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            }
        });     
});

//CREATE ARRAY OF CHECKBOX VALUES
$('#checkform').on('click','.boxcheck', function(){
    var check = $(this).prop("checked");
    var val = "";
    var tempId = $(this).attr('id');

    if(check === true){
        val = "checked";
        console.log(val);
        var tempArr = {
            "id": tempId,
            "val": val
        };
        checkArr.push(tempArr);
    } else if (check === false){
        val = "";
        console.log(val);

        for (var i = checkArr.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            if (checkArr[i].id == tempId) {
                checkArr[i].id = tempId;
                checkArr[i].val = val;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(checkArr);
});


//CHANGE COLOUR OF ITEMS
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
    var current = $(this);

    if(current.is(':checked')){
        current.parents("li").removeClass('incomplete');
        current.parents("li").addClass('complete');
    } else {
        current.parents("li").removeClass('complete');
        current.parents("li").addClass('incomplete');
    }
});

//SUBMIT CHECKBOX VALUES TO PHP
$('#submitCheck').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(checkArr);
    $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {checkArr:checkArr},
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                alert("ok");
            }
        });     
});
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST); ` yield?

Comment: give `console.log(checkArr)` just above the ajax call, and check whether you are getting the value there

Comment: is your ajax post is inside document ready? `$(document).ready(function () { //your code });`

Comment: @AswinRamesh good idea, it appears to be completely blank somehow...didn't expect that. 
I am initialising checkArr as an empty array at the beginning of my .js document but only then, if i move that to document ready i am unable to use the variable outside of it.

Comment: @user27 no it isn't, it is called only when i click submit on the checkbox form.

Comment: @DoodlesThen I think it might be problem with hoisting, i guess can you share you full code

Comment: @Doodles try preventing the default action of your submit button. `$('#submitCheck').on('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); //your code });`

Comment: @user27 unfortunately still the same

Comment: Adding full code snippet in Edit: @AswinRamesh

Comment: @Doodles your code seems working for me, Can you plz check whether your are getting the output for  `console.log(checkArr);` inside the clickhandler `$('#checkform').on('click','.boxcheck', function(){`

Comment: @AswinRamesh i definitely am getting the array in console.log

Comment: To check if it's receiving in php i've written

`if(isset($_POST['checkArr'])){
$arr = $_POST['checkArr'];
echo $arr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting here to update just in case anyone has a similar problem, the code itself was correct(sort of), after a lot of digging and asking around, it turns out the local server i was using, XAMPP, had too small a POST upload limit hence the empty array on the php side, increasing the php.ini upload limit from 2mb to 10mb finally fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it's working perfectly for me.

Now the only thing I can think of is your `url` in your ajax request. make sure you are really submitting to `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify()`  to submit the array from ajax to php